# Create multidimensional array from newly combined arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a couple of arrays that I want to combine into new arrays but each new array needs to have one value from each value. Just creating a multidimensional array is not enough. So any help would be great.

I have this array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Supplier 1
        [1] => Supplier 1
        [2] => Supplier 2
    ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Product 1 
        [1] => Product 2
        [2] => Product 3 
    ) 

    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 123456 
        [1] => 654321 
        [2] => 111111 
    ) 

    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 7 
        [1] => 40 
        [2] => 5 
    ) 
)
```

But I need it to be like this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [supplier] => Supplier 1
        [descr] => Product 1 
        [partid] => 123456
        [quantity] => 7
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [supplier] => Supplier 1
        [descr] => Product 2
        [partid] => 654321
        [quantity] => 40
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [supplier] => Supplier 2
        [descr] => Product 3
        [partid] => 111111
        [quantity] => 5
    )
)
```

Comment: I have not tried much, I just searched for a similar problem but could not find anything I could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP method `array_map`[1] to perform this (assuming that your original multi-dimensional array is in `$arr`):

```
$res = array_map(
    function ($lev, $oms, $num, $aan) {
        return [
            'leverancier' => $lev,
            'artikel_omschrijving' => $oms,
            'artikelnummer' => $num,
            'artikel_aantal' => $aan
        ];
    },
    $arr[3],
    $arr[1],
    $arr[0],
    $arr[2]);
```

What it does is loop through all `n` arrays passed at the end of the function call, and passes the entry at the same position in each array to the callback function.

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$input = array ( 
    '3'=>array ( 
        0 => '200046 - Aswo Service B.V.' ,
        1 => '200046 - Aswo Service B.V.' ,
        2 => '200013 - Weststrate verpakkingen' ,
    ),

    '1'=>array ( 
        0 => 'Diode 1N 4007 1000V 1A' ,
        1 => 'Tyrap wit - 100x2,5mm' ,
        2 => 'Kartonnen doos 50x35x35 cm' ,
    ),

    '0'=>array ( 
        0 => '11-00055' ,
        1 => '100538' ,
        2 => '100500' ,
    ),

    '2'=>array ( 
        0 => '7' ,
        1 => '40' ,
        2 => '5' ,
    ) 
);

$result = array();

$loopLength = count($input[0]);

for($i = 0; $i < $loopLength; $i++)
{
    $singleResult = array();
    $singleResult['leverancier'] = $input[3][$i];
    $singleResult['artikel_omschrijving'] = $input[1][$i];
    $singleResult['artikel_nummer'] = $input[0][$i];
    $singleResult['artikel_aantal'] = $input[2][$i];

    $result[] = $singleResult;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [leverancier] => 200046 - Aswo Service B.V.
            [artikel_omschrijving] => Diode 1N 4007 1000V 1A
            [artikel_nummer] => 11-00055
            [artikel_aantal] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [leverancier] => 200046 - Aswo Service B.V.
            [artikel_omschrijving] => Tyrap wit - 100x2,5mm
            [artikel_nummer] => 100538
            [artikel_aantal] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [leverancier] => 200013 - Weststrate verpakkingen
            [artikel_omschrijving] => Kartonnen doos 50x35x35 cm
            [artikel_nummer] => 100500
            [artikel_aantal] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Pleasure is mine :) So if you like my answer (or other user answer), please accept it as a best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Unified solution(for any number of elements) with `array_unshift`, `call_user_func_array`, `array_map` and `array_combine` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array

$keys = ['leverancier', 'artikel_omschrijving', 'artikelnummer', 'artikel_aantal'];
array_unshift($arr, null);

$res = call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr);

$result = array_map(function($v) use (&$keys){
    return array_combine($keys, $v);
}, $res);

var_dump($result); // this will return the expected result
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'leverancier' => string '200046 - Aswo Service B.V.' (length=26)
      'artikel_omschrijving' => string 'Diode 1N 4007 1000V 1A.' (length=23)
      'artikelnummer' => string '11-00055' (length=8)
      'artikel_aantal' => int 7
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'leverancier' => string '200046 - Aswo Service B.V.' (length=26)
      'artikel_omschrijving' => string 'Tyrap wit - 100x2,5mm' (length=21)
      'artikelnummer' => int 100538
      'artikel_aantal' => int 40
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'leverancier' => string '200013 - Weststrate verpakkingen' (length=32)
      'artikel_omschrijving' => string 'Kartonnen doos 50x35x35 cm' (length=26)
      'artikelnummer' => int 100500
      'artikel_aantal' => int 5
```